# Python count iterations of recursive call

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to count the number of times the collatz_chain() function is called recursively. In particular, the code below seems to set the count variable to 1 at the end (outside of the recursive calls) even though it is incremented correctly inside the recursive function.

```
def collatz_longest_chain(limit):
    iter = 1
    while(iter < limit):
        count = 0
        _next_num, count = collatz_chain(iter, count)
        iter += 1

    print('----')
    return count

def collatz_chain(n, count):
    if n == 1:
        count += 1
        print("n=1" + " count: " + str(count) + " | inside n == 1")
        return 1, count
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
        print("n: " + str(n) + " count: " + str(count) + " | inside n % 2 == 0")
        return collatz_chain(n/2, count), count
    else:
        count += 1
        print("n: " + str(n) + " count: " + str(count) + " | inside 3*n + 1")
        return collatz_chain(3*n + 1, count), count

print(collatz_longest_chain(10))
```

The output is:

```
...
n: 9 count: 1 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 28 count: 2 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 14.0 count: 3 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 7.0 count: 4 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 22.0 count: 5 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 11.0 count: 6 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 34.0 count: 7 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 17.0 count: 8 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 52.0 count: 9 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 26.0 count: 10 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 13.0 count: 11 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 40.0 count: 12 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 20.0 count: 13 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 10.0 count: 14 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 5.0 count: 15 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 16.0 count: 16 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 8.0 count: 17 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 4.0 count: 18 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 2.0 count: 19 | inside n % 2 == 0
n=1 count: 20 | inside n == 1
----
1
```

How can I pass the correct count variable value out of the recursive call, so that the output would be:

```
...
n=1 count: 20 | inside n == 1
----
20
```

Comment: can you explain what you are tyring to do here?

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky - please see Mark's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base case you are returning a tuple and the count:

```
return 1, count
```

But in the recursive calls you are returning the result of the recursion (which is a tuple) and the count

```
return collatz_chain(3*n + 1, count), count
# collatz_chain already returns the count
```

so you end up returning a long nested tuple in `_next_num`. If you want the the final count returned, you need to return values from the recursive calls in the same shape as the base case with something like:

```
def collatz_chain(n, count):
    count += 1
    if n == 1:
        print("n=1" + " count: " + str(count) + " | inside n == 1")
        return 1, count
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        print("n: " + str(n) + " count: " + str(count) + " | inside n % 2 == 0")
        return collatz_chain(n/2, count)
    else:
        print("n: " + str(n) + " count: " + str(count) + " | inside 3*n + 1")
        return collatz_chain(3*n + 1, count)
```

This will print:

```
n: 20.0 count: 13 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 10.0 count: 14 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 5.0 count: 15 | inside 3*n + 1
n: 16.0 count: 16 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 8.0 count: 17 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 4.0 count: 18 | inside n % 2 == 0
n: 2.0 count: 19 | inside n % 2 == 0
n=1 count: 20 | inside n == 1
----
20
```

However, note that this is not the *total* calls to `collatz_chain()`. It is the number of recursive calls in the last invocation of your `while` loop.

If you want the total count you need to use the above changes and then take the total of all the calls from the while loop. Something like:

```
def collatz_longest_chain(limit):
    iter = 1
    total_count = 0
    while(iter < limit):
        count = 0
        print("calling iter: ", iter, count)
        _next_num, count = collatz_chain(iter, count)
        iter += 1
        total_count += count

    print('----')
    return count, total_count
```

One other note: `iter` is a built-in function in Python, so you probably shouldn't use it as a variable name. It will overwrite the built-in.